# set mail.app as default mail client for emacs

Tags: emacs, email-client, org-mode

Opening a link `mailto:foo@bar.com` in org-mode opens a new buffer in `Message MML` mode.

How can I set it to use `mail.app` under mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(setq browse-url-mailto-function 'browse-url-generic)
(setq browse-url-generic-program "open")
```

Since the default value of `org-link-mailto-program` is to use `browse-url`, this will cause `open` to be called on `mailto:` links, which opens Mail.app for me.